# Node.js web application browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I heard node.js is an ideal framework for building real time web application (chatting, live feeds etc...), then i guess it involve lot of socket io connection between nodejs and client browser.

in client side do i have to use websocket(html5) in order to communicate with node.js, if that is the case, then most of the older browser won't support HTML5-Websocket.

**Question :** 
*are real time web applications built using node.js will work only with HTML5 compatible browsers.?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many nodejs chat applications use [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

socket.io has a fallback (involving pulling or Flash) for browsers not having websockets :

> Socket.IO aims to make realtime apps possible in every browser and
>   mobile device, blurring the differences between the different
>   transport mechanisms. It's care-free realtime 100% in JavaScript.

The point of using socket.io is that you don't really care, you just use it and most browsers will use websockets while some won't (but they still will work as well as possible).

Comment: if it goes to fallback mode, then it's no longer be a real time web app right.?

Comment: @mycholan There are a few fallbacks. The lowest one is pulling. It's no real *real time*, yes, but it's well made enough to be usable for most usecases.

Comment: i accept node.js asynchronous nature, single process for all request, scalability ...,  but if client doesn't support socket io then there is no advantage over LAMP stack. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Doing an efficient pulling isn't easy. socket.io does it for you. And your server will have to support this only for a few clients.

Answer (score 1):

> I heard node.js is an ideal framework for building real time web application (chatting, live >feeds etc...), then i guess it involve lot of socket io connection between nodejs and client >browser.

Yes, what you have heard is correct. It does involve a socket.io connection between client browser and the server

[Read more about socket.io here](http://socket.io/)

> in client side do i have to use websocket(html5) in order to communicate with node.js, if >that is the case, then most of the older browser won't support HTML5-Websocket.

[socket.io](http://socket.io/) package of Node JS creates a WebSocket connection internally, if the client is using HTML5 enabled browser. In other browsers, it will fall back gracefully to different transport mechanisms.

> Question : are real time web applications built using node.js will work only with HTML5 >compatible browsers.?

Above comments must have made clear, it will work in all supported browsers, if you use socket.io :)
[See Browser support for socket.io](http://socket.io/#browser-support)

Comment: i got it, see my comment for @dystroy, the real time advantage will be gone if it goes to fall back mode, so i don't see any advantage over LAMP stack. am i right.?

Comment: It will be useful.. Real-time advantage won't be lost.. Transport Mechanisms `Adobe Flash Socket` is as good as using `WebSocket`. While other transport mechanisms like `AJAX long polling` are real time but consume more server resources. I suggest that you search for "Long pooling" on google and learn what exactly it is. You will learn that it is very much real-time in nature