# PHP "PUSH" To Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, long-polling, ajax-push

Right now we have a web application that is ran on a local network where the clients run everything in javascript. In order to make sure everything is in sync these clients currently utilize an AJAX request to the server by sending the last "syncId" that it has recieved. The server then responds with an array tree of commands to get this client up to date.  This is executed every second and has yet to cause any issues with network bandwith or latency however we are installing a system in a bigger client next month that may push the limits of this method and I am wondering if it is feasible to have the server "PUSH" the sync events to the clients in real time.

```js
srvResponse=httpGet("CDSSync.php?sessionKey="+sessionKey+"&lastUpdate="+lastUpdate);
if(srvResponse!=0){
    syncEvents=srvResponse.split(";");
    for(var i=0; i<syncEvents.length; i++){
         syncItem=syncEvents[i].split(",");
         window["syncFunction_"+syncItem[1]](syncItem[2]);
         lastUpdate=syncItem[0];
     }
}
```

The above is where my system checks for events to be synced where syncItem[0] is a autoIncrement ID, syncItem[1] is a code for the event being handled and syncItem[2] is a parameter for the function. the httpGet function being called although not in this code is just a function that fetches from the server and returns the response.

Comment: You should have a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

Comment: Alright i will. I figured it would have to be a socket! I was just kinda hoping that there would be some nice little push functionality built into jscript or jquery.

Comment: @mapek i see socket.io is based on nodes.js. Does nodes.js and socket.io work with browsers without the nodes runtime environment installed?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/22015350

Comment: Maybe it could help : http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at www.firebase.com, you can set up a push service from javascript clients to all others in minutes. Try the simple tutorial first:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/resources/tutorial/css/example.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='messagesDiv'></div>
    <input type='text' id='nameInput' placeholder='Name'>
    <input type='text' id='messageInput' placeholder='Message'>
    <script>
      var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://hbw30ob2a8y.firebaseio-demo.com/');
      $('#messageInput').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          var name = $('#nameInput').val();
          var text = $('#messageInput').val();
          myDataRef.push({name: name, text: text});
          $('#messageInput').val('');
        }
      });
      myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        var message = snapshot.val();
        displayChatMessage(message.name, message.text);
      });
      function displayChatMessage(name, text) {
        $('<div/>').text(text).prepend($('<em/>').text(name+': ')).appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
        $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: our software communicates only across a local area network and many clients dont even have internet service